# Who to rent virtual private server from accepts bitcoin?

Tags: services

Have preferences for service. Desirable that machine hosted in nation disagreeable with United States. Standard linux images available.

Will create webpage which lists links to youtube videos, expect accusations of copyright infringement. Good if host tells Hollywood companies where to stuff court papers. Service in Russia, former Bloc nations, China all good.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of VPS hosts on the [Bitcoin Wiki page for Trade](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Dedicated.2FVirtual_Server_Hosting). Some of them list what countries they come from. There is also a [neat list of all the VPS servers](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Virtual_private_server). At the time of writing, only [CINIPAC](http://www.cinipac.com/) appears to be anywhere close to your desired locations, being from Romania.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good providers, try YOKU Cloud and bitvps

ref: http://www.yokucloud.com

ref: http://www.bitvbs.net

Comment: What is bitvbs.net? I can't access it from any of my machines, and other pages tell me it's [down](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/bitvbs.net).

Answer (score 0):

Cosmic Fantasia http://cosmicfantasia.net.au is a reseller for vps.net and accepts Bitcoin for payment. You get all the world wide data centres, templates and reliability of vps.net and can ay with Bitcoins. Works for me

Comment: You're the founder of Cosmic Fantasia, aren't you?

Comment: It's usually best to disclose that sort of thing up front.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase VPS with BitCoin currency from http://www.QHoster.com.
They also offer domain names with BTC. It is instant activation VPS though.